# What can we say for this situation?

Tags: idioms

There is a piece of work but no-one wants to do it  and it seems that you are the only one that will do it. So the burden will be on your shoulders. What idiom can I use?

For example: *This work will be pushed to me* or *This job will be explode in my hands*?

Comment: I would have said "_this job is a **poisoned pill**_" would have fitted, but the only definitions I can find (e.g. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poison%20pill)) only mention it specifically related to finance as a way of stopping an unwanted takeover.

Answer (score 1):

There's an idiom that goes ...

> **be left holding the baby**
>   *(North American **be left holding the bag**)*
>   Be left with an unwelcome responsibility, typically without warning.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be_left_holding_the_baby)

Comment: This is the closest so far I think. Interestingly Collins Dictionary has a regional note for America of "to be left holding the bag."

Comment: @Zebrafish Thanks. It's in the ODO entry as well - I've now added it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll be stuck with this job.

Stuck = past tense of [Stick](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick) (MW verb definition 9)

> to saddle with something disadvantageous or disagreeable  - "is still stuck with that lousy car"

Answer (score 0):

**[fall on/upon somebody/something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fall-on-upon)**

> phrasal verb
> **1** if a duty or job falls on someone, they are responsible for doing it
> *The responsibility usually falls on the mother.*

*More Examples:*
*The task of telling Mother about the broken vase fell upon Jane.

The job of cleaning up the spill fell upon Tom.*

"It will **fall upon me to** do this task."
i.e., I, and only I will have to do this task (as no one else will do it).

Answer (score -1):

> This job will be explode in my hands?

Focusing on the unpleasantness of the job itself, you could say, "This job is **[a recipe for disaster](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-recipe-for-disaster)**."

> [Collins]
>
> If you say that something is a recipe for disaster, you mean that it is very likely to have unpleasant consequences.